# Is a Lipschitz continuous gradient equivalent to this condition?

Tags: convex-optimization, convexity, nonlinear-optimization, convex-analysis, smoothness

I know if a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is $L$-smooth, i.e. its gradient $\nabla f$ is $L$-Lipschitz continuous, then it satisfies the following inequality for any $x, x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$:
$$
\left| f(x) - \left( f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0)^\top (x - x_0)\right) \right| \leq \frac{L}{2} \lVert x - x_0 \rVert_2^2
\text{.}
$$

Here's my question: is the converse true? I know that, provided $f$ is convex, then we can conclude that $f$ satisfying the above inequality must be $L$-smooth. But what if $f$ is not necessarily convex?
If the converse is false, can you give some counterexamples?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but this post https://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/Lipschitz-gradient does explicitly say that this implication does not hold without convexity (but does not give a counterexample).

Comment: @Dirk Still very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the converse is also true. This follows from the answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4227159/characterization-of-lipschitz-derivative.

In fact, your condition yields
$$
| (\nabla f(x_0) - \nabla f(x))^\top (x_0 - x) | \le L \| x_0 - x \|_2^2
$$
and the linked answer then gives the Lipschitzness of $\nabla f$.